# Bootstrap datetimepicker glyphicon calendar doesn't open

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am trying to use Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker. But the glyphicon calendar doesn't open. See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vqsss5fx/

```js
$(function () {

    var data = [
        { rank: 1, company: 'Exxon Mobil', DatePicker: '04/04/1990 00:00', revenues: '339938.0', profits: '36130.0' },
        { rank: 2, company: 'Wal-Mart Stores', DatePicker: '05/03/2014 00:00', revenues: '315654.0', profits: '11231.0' },
        
    ];
    var obj = { 
      
        title: "ParamQuery Grid with JSON Data",      
        scrollModel:{autoFit:true, theme:true}
    };
    obj.colModel = [
        { title: "Rank", width: 100, dataType: "integer", dataIndx: "rank" },
        { title: "Company", width: 200, dataType: "string", dataIndx: "company" },
  { title: "DatePicker", width: 200, dataType: "string", dataIndx: "date",editable:false, 
   render : function(){
    var date = '<div class="form-group" style="width:150px;margin-left:50px;text-align:center"><div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker123"><input type="text" value="04/05/2012 00:00" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span></div></div>';
                                                                                                                                                                        
    return date;
   }
   },
        { title: "Revenues ($ millions)", width: 150, dataType: "float", align: "right", dataIndx: "revenues" },
      
    ];
 
  $('body').on('mouseover','.input-group',function() {  
  
  $("#datetimepicker123").datetimepicker();
  });
 
    obj.dataModel = { data: data };
 
    $("#grid_json").pqGrid(obj);
 
});
```

```html
<div id="grid_json" style="margin:100px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three problems:

- You have multiple HTML elements with the same ID (#datetimepicker123): please avoid it!
- Instead of `$("#datetimepicker123").datetimepicker();` you should use `$(".input-group.date").datetimepicker();` to add a timepicker to every date input.
- The timepicker appears, but it's truncated by the HTML Cell (you can see the arrow under the input field). Some CSS customization might be required:

  ```
  .pq-grid-cell{
      overflow:visible;
  }
  ```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/vqsss5fx/3/

Comment: Still the same problem I am facing. The calendar is open but it is truncated inside a cell.

Comment: You might use the `!important` rule, to override the defined style (that's how I did with the jsfiddle linked into my answer)

Comment: Is this possible to open calendar always downside.

Comment: I don't understand "open downside"

Comment: Means calendar is displaying above the cell. I want  to display the calendar always bottom of the cell.

Comment: Take a look at the doc: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#widgetpositioning